# Changing background-image with jquery fadeTo() animation fails after a while

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-animate, fadeto

**Update: I found a better way of doing this. There's a library called [Backstretch](https://www.jquery-backstretch.com/).

 I hope it will be helpful for someone else.**

I'm trying to change the background of the  tag every 10 seconds with animation but after a while of working, it does change every 2-3 seconds instead of 10.

What is wrong with the code? Why does it go crazy after a while of waiting as I explained above? For example, after about 10 minutes or so.

```html
<section class='set-bg'>...</section>
```

```js
$('.set-bg').each(function() {
  var bgs = [];
  $.get('/api/listbanners', (e) => {
    bgs = e["background"];
    x(0);
  });

  function x(i) {
    $('.set-bg').css('background-image', 'url(' + bgs[i] + ')').fadeTo(0, 0.6).fadeTo(1000, 1);
    i++;
    if (i == bgs.length) {
      i = 0;
    }
    setTimeout(x, 10000, i);
  }
});
```

Comment: It's because you're defining an interval for every `.set-bg` element. Ie. you have 5 elements, that's 5 counters, each updating every `.set-bg` element every 10 seconds. These start off out of sync (due to the multiple AJAX requests and how long they take to respond) and get more out of sync as the page is left open as JS timing is notoriously unreliable. As such the first timer runs and sets the image, while another runs a little later and sets them all again. To fix this, use a single timer to update all the elements.

Comment: I have only 1  .set-bg element

Comment: Well that avoids that problem, but you should remove the `each()` call

Comment: Alright, I removed it. Hope it fixes the problem.

Comment: It's almost been 15 minutes, works fine but still waiting.